# Difference between two function calls - Swift

Tags: swift

What is the difference between these two Swift functions. I don't quite understand it. I know they are two different functions but they have different parameter structures.

```
func addTwoIntegers(first x:Int, second y:Int) -> Int{
      return x + y
}

func multiplyTwoIntegers(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int{
     return x * y
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two functions are evident if you use them inside of Swift’s playground. The first function uses external naming parameters which allow you to see the name of the parameters in kind of an Objective-c style fashion. For example, when I call `addTwoIntegers`, I will be able to call it like this while passing in the arguments `addTwoIntegers(first: x, second: y)`. The second function does not use external naming parameters so you can only call it passing in the arguments such as `multiplyTwoIntegers(2,2)`

Copy this code into Xcode’s playground.

```
func addTwoIntegers(first x:Int, second y:Int) -> Int{
    return x + y
}

func multiplyTwoIntegers(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int{
    return x * y    
}


var x = addTwoIntegers(first: 10, second: 10)    
var y = multiplyTwoIntegers(2, 2)

println(x)
println(y)
```

Comment: Note:  your example is true for Swift 1.2 and below.  For Swift 2.0, the second line is `var y = multiplyTwoIntegers(2, y: 2)` since Swift 2.0 follows the same rules for standalone functions as methods (when external names are not provided, the first local name is not used, and all of the rest are required).

Answer (score 1):

The first uses externally named parameters as well as local parameter names and the second uses just locally name parameters